# If $p:\tilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ is a covering map and $X$ locally path connected, then prove that $\tilde{X}$ is locally path connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $p:\widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ is a covering map and $X$ locally path connected, then prove that $\widetilde{X}$ is locally path connected. I try to prove it by these arguments.

Let $\widetilde{x} \in \widetilde{X}$ and $U$ be a open neighborhood of $\widetilde{x}$. Since $p$ is a covering map, $p$ is an open map and $f(U)$ is open. Since $X$ is locally path connected, there exists an open neighborhood $U'$ of $p(\widetilde{x})$ which is path connected. Then $p^{-1}(U') \subset U$ is open. We will show that $p^{-1}(U')$ is path connected.

Since $p$ is a covering map, there exists open neighborhood of $U"$ of $p(\tilde{x})$ that is evenly covered by $p$. Let $p^{-1}(U’’)=\bigsqcup_{j \in J} V_j$. Hence, $U' \cap U" \subset U’’$ is an open neighborhood of  $p(\widetilde{x})$ and $p^{-1}(U’’ \cap U')$ is open.

Because $U' \cap U’’ \subset U’’$, $U' \cap U’’$ is evenly covered by $p$ and $p^{-1}(U' \cap U’’)=\bigsqcup_{j \in J} V_j$ with $p|_{V_j}:V_j \longrightarrow U' \cap U’’$ is a homeomorphism.

Claim : $V= p^{-1}(U' \cap ‘’)$ is path connected. Take $\widetilde{y} \in V$. Suppose that $\widetilde{x} \in V_1$ and $\widetilde{y} \in V_2$. We will find a path $\widetilde{f}$ in $V$ from $\widetilde{x}$ to $\widetilde{y}$. Since $p(\widetilde{x}), p(\widetilde{y}) \in U'$, there exists path  $f:I \longrightarrow U'$ with $f(0)=p(\widetilde{x})$ and $f(1)=p(\widetilde{y})$.

But I have a problem to find the $\widetilde{f}$. Am I on the right path? Can you give me some suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you assume any properties on $X$ or $\widetilde{X}$ when you say $p$ is a covering map? Or are they completely general spaces? Texts differ in this.

Comment: You could use the main theorem of (path) connectedness: given a continuous function $f:X\to Y$, if $X$ is (path) connected, so is $Y$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't think any additional properties on $X$ or $\widetilde{X}$ are relevant here.

Comment: @Caffeine You need to assume $f$ is surjective for this to be true.

Comment: @Wojowu In most texts this is automatically assumed in the definition of a covering map.

Comment: This is a somewhat general phenomenon, many "locally blah" properties can be lifted from a space to a covering space using evenly-covered neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$ be a covering map and $x\in \widetilde{X}$. The crucial observation is that since $p$ is a covering map then there is some open neighbourhood $V\subseteq X$ of $p(x)$ and some open neighbourhood $U\subseteq\widetilde{X}$ of $x$ such that the restriction $p_{|U}:U\to V$ is a **homeomorphism**. The way we utilize this is that preimages of (path)connected subsets via homeomorphism are again (path)connected.

Now let $U'\subseteq\widetilde{X}$ be an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $x$. We want to show that $U'$ has an open path connected subneighbourhood. Consider $U''=U'\cap U$ and note that $p(U'')$ is an open neighbourhood of $p(x)$. Since $X$ is locally path connected, then $p(U'')$ has a path connected subneighbourhood $V'\subseteq p(U'')\subseteq V$ of $p(x)$. And since $p_{|U}:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism then $p_{|U}^{-1}(V')=p^{-1}(V')\cap U$ is an open path connected subneighbourhood of $U''$, and ergo of $U'$, which completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

If $y \in \widetilde{X}$ then we can find a path-connected evenly covered neighbourhood $U$ of $x=p(y)$ and let the component of $p^{-1}[U]$ that contains $y$ be called $O_y$. So $p$ is a **homeomorphism** between $O_y$ and $U$.

If now $O$ is any open neighbourhood of $y$, $O \cap O_y$ is also an open neighbourhood of $y$ and $p[O \cap O_y]$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and so contains a path-connected neighbourhood $P$ and then $p^{-1}[P]$ is a path-connected neighbourhood of $y$ inside $O$, as required.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forget that we can have a path connected neighborhood $U$ that is evenly covered by $p$ and it is very useful.